# XML Etree insert element not changing the element.text value

Tags: python, xml, elementtree

**Problem Description**

I'm trying to add "ORDER" element to the people.xml document Record based on the value from the DATE element:

*people.xml:*

```
<Data>
    <People>
        <Record>
            <NAME>STEVE</NAME>
            <DATE>2014-09-30</DATE>
            <AGE>25</AGE>
        </Record>
        <Record>
            <NAME>ANGIE</NAME>
            <DATE>2014-11-30</DATE>
            <AGE>25</AGE>
        </Record>
        <Record>
            <NAME>BART</NAME>
            <DATE>2014-12-31</DATE>
            <AGE>25</AGE>
        </Record>
        <Record>
            <NAME>LUCY</NAME>
            <DATE>2019-12-31</DATE>
            <AGE>25</AGE>
        </Record>
    </People>   
</Data>
```

the value of the order element is specified in the following dictionary:

```
orderDictionary = 
{"2014-09-30":"4",
 "2014-11-30":"3",
 "2014-12-31":"2",
 "2019-12-31":"1"
}
```

So the XML document after the modification should look like this:

```
<Data>
    <People>
        <Record>
            <NAME>STEVE</NAME>
            <DATE>2014-09-30</DATE>
            <AGE>25</AGE>
            <ORDER>4</ORDER>
        </Record>
        <Record>
            <NAME>ANGIE</NAME>
            <DATE>2014-11-30</DATE>
            <AGE>25</AGE>
            <ORDER>3</ORDER>
        </Record>
        <Record>
            <NAME>BART</NAME>
            <DATE>2014-12-31</DATE>
            <AGE>25</AGE>
            <ORDER>2</ORDER>
        </Record>
        <Record>
            <NAME>LUCY</NAME>
            <DATE>2019-12-31</DATE>
            <AGE>25</AGE>
            <ORDER>1</ORDER>
        </Record>
    </People>   
</Data>
```

**Steps taken to resolve the problem**

I tried creating the following python script to add the ORDER element into the records in the xml file.

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
tree = ET.parse("people.xml")
root = tree.getroot()

records = root.findall('People/Record')
orderDictionary = {
"2014-09-30":"4",
"2014-11-30":"3",
"2014-12-31":"2",
"2019-12-31":"1"
}

newElement = ET.Element("ORDER")

for record in records:
    date = record.find("DATE").text
    elementText = orderDictionary[date]
    newElement.text = elementText
    record.insert(3, newElement)

tree.write("peopleModified.xml")
```

After running the code above the peopleModified.xml looks like this:

```
<Data>
    <People>
        <Record>
            <NAME>STEVE</NAME>
            <DATE>2014-09-30</DATE>
            <AGE>25</AGE>
            <ORDER>1</ORDER>
        </Record>
        <Record>
            <NAME>ANGIE</NAME>
            <DATE>2014-11-30</DATE>
            <AGE>25</AGE>
            <ORDER>1</ORDER>
        </Record>
        <Record>
            <NAME>BART</NAME>
            <DATE>2014-12-31</DATE>
            <AGE>25</AGE>
            <ORDER>1</ORDER>
        </Record>
        <Record>
            <NAME>LUCY</NAME>
            <DATE>2019-12-31</DATE>
            <AGE>25</AGE>
            <ORDER>1</ORDER>
        </Record>
    </People>   
</Data>
```

For some reason the value of the ORDER element is always "1". 
I was also trying to print the newElement.text in the for loop and values that were printed were correct.

I'm pretty sure that the resolution is straightforward, but I have no idea how to resolve :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is in this line 
    newElement = ET.Element("ORDER")

This line has to be placed inside the for loop, the element has to be recreated for each iteration, otherwise it keeps the same reference and the final value when it actually outputs the xml is the one from the last iteration, in the above case "1".